# How to select dataframe rows between two datetimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having trouble selecting rows from a dataframe with a datetime column from a CSV file.  I have my code and my sample data.  There are no rows returned.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col_names = ['date','msft','nok','aapl','ibm','amzn']
stockprices = pd.read_csv('./stockdata.csv', skiprows=1, names=col_names)
stockprices.loc['2018-01-01 9:00:00':'2018-01-01 11:00:00']
```

CSV file data:

```
        date               msft   nok   aapl   ibm  amzn 
    2018-01-01 08:00:00     107     2   161    140  1295
    2018-01-01 09:00:00     112     1   143    130  1298 
    2018-01-01 10:00:00     109    10   185    137  1647 
    2018-01-01 11:00:00      98    11   146    105  1331
    2018-01-01 12:00:00      83    3    214    131  1355
```

Basically, trying to select the 3 rows with 9:00:00, 10:00:00 and 11:00:00 times in the dataframe.

Is using the .loc the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`pd.date_range`**

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-01-01 09:00:00', periods=3, freq='1H')

# Result
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 09:00:00', '2018-01-01 10:00:00',
           '2018-01-01 11:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

**`to_datetime`**

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

**`loc`**

```
df.loc[(df.date >= i[0]) & (df.date <= i[-1])]

                 date  msft  nok  aapl  ibm  amzn
1 2018-01-01 09:00:00   112    1   143  130  1298
2 2018-01-01 10:00:00   109   10   185  137  1647
3 2018-01-01 11:00:00    98   11   146  105  1331
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite understanding your solution.  It looks like 3 different ways of doing this.  The loc method looks like you are using an index?  Can you please explain your approach?

Comment: These are the three steps I used to solve the problem.  First, create a date range, then convert your column to datetime, then use `loc`

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Comment: I have pandas datetime column and two other start and end date time which I got from another dataframe. I am using this method, but I get this error: `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple dates

you can get it by `converting` to `DateTime` and `filter`

```
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df[df["date"].between('2018-01-01 09:00:00','2018-01-01 11:00:00')]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df[df['date'].dt.hour.between(9,11)]
```

Output:

```
                 date  msft  nok  aapl  ibm  amzn 
1 2018-01-01 09:00:00   112    1   143  130   1298
2 2018-01-01 10:00:00   109   10   185  137   1647
3 2018-01-01 11:00:00    98   11   146  105   1331
```

use `between` and `hour` to slice your desired dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

**df.loc** is used for **label based rows filtering**. when your dataframe have labels you can use for filtering or by default it starts 0 to n.

```
dt_range = pd.date_range('2018-01-01 09:00:00', periods=3, freq='1H')
stockprices['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(stockprices['date'])

result = stockprices[stockprices['dt'].apply(lambda x: dt_range[0] <= x  and  dt_range[len(dt_range)-1] >= x)]
print("result df" , result )
```